# In what conditons DB will not close the cursor when executing a select query from cpp?

Tags: c++, sql, database, database-cursor

I have a piece of code in cpp which transforms to looks like this:

```
DBConnection dbConn;
SelectStatement selectStatement;
while (SOME_CONDITION){
1.Add conditon to selectStatement;
2.Execute select statement;
3.resultSet.next()
}
```

What i am observing is everytime it runs while loop it does not close the cursor but creates a new cursor.
Please suggest the reason and possible resolution for the same.

Comment: What database API are you using? What does its docs say about this?

Comment: You should also update your post to include a minimal *complete* example, not psuedocode.

Comment: Sorry Shawn, but I can not add any part of the code as its a propritery code.

Comment: Mat, I will get this info and get back to you.

Comment: Mat , We are using ORA11G OCI for connection

Answer (score 0):

It was because same variable was being used to create new connections and close it there.But it seems there is a concept until the variable is destroyed Oracle keeps the cursor open and for any new cursor requirement it will create a new one.